# Mailchimp Keeps disabling my API key, when I try to use signup form in my rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp, api-key, gibbon

I am a noob at RoR, so forgive me if this is a stupid question.

I am trying to have user subscription form in my simple app.

I basically followed this guide to get it work

http://cheshireoctopus.github.io/blog/2014/01/23/mailchimp-plus-gibbon-plus-rails-create-a-basic-sign-up-form/

My code is working and I can signup with the form, however, I keep getting email from mailchimp telling me that my keep has been compromised. Sometimes I get this email after I try to send some test subscription, othertimes I just get it after I change my api key again.

> I wanted to reach out to you to let you know that we had to disable an active API Key in your MailChimp account with the account name MYACCOUNTNAME.
>
> We were able to find your API Key posted publicly, which gives someone full access to your account. Since it's been disabled, we don't recommend re-enabling it. Instead, you'll need to generate a new API Key in your account.

Am I suppose to somehow encrypt my key or something? Btw, my app is on Heroku. So How do I stop my keys from being disabled?

Comment: Do you host your repository on github, or anywhere publicly available? That might be the issue.

Comment: ah thats right.. I push my code to github.. so my gibbon.rb file with my config is the reason? So I should add it to my gitignore file?

Comment: well, if you put it to gitignore, it won't be on production as well, and the production server won't be able to access mailchimp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably host your code on **github**, and, as the repository is public, even google robots can index it. Scammers can use your credentials as well.

There is nothing bad hosting repository on github, though. Just use [environment variables](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) instead of storing the credentials in the code.

config/initializers/gibbon.rb:

```
Gibbon::API.api_key = ENV[:api_key]
```

To set environment variable on heroku:

```
heroku config:set api_key=<your key>
```

Comment: I am not quite understanding here. 

i need to initialize gibbon in gibbon.rb

`Gibbon::API.api_key = "MY API KEY"
 Gibbon::API.timeout = 15
 Gibbon::API.throws_exceptions = false`

if i dont put the key there,how will gibbon know what the key is?

Comment: Well, your mailchimp credentials, stored in `/config/initializers/gibbon.rb`, can be used by a scammer to take control over your mailchimp account and you payment data.

Comment: Ah I see! but now How will I test my setup on my local enviroment? Since my local enviroment wont have access to the enviromental variable hosted on heroku?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have figured this out.

For production environment(heroku), I followed the solution that roman provided above.

for my local enviroment, I installed Figaro Gem, which basically keeps my api key secret in an application.yml file in the config folder. It works greate.

https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro

here is my gibbon.rb initilizer file incase anyone is wondering

```
if Rails.env.development?
   Gibbon::API.api_key = ENV["MC_key"]
end

if Rails.env.production?
   Gibbon::API.api_key = ENV[:api_key]
end
Gibbon::API.timeout = 15
Gibbon::API.throws_exceptions = false
```

Where MC_Key is the variable in my application.yml and :api_key is the ENV in heroku.

hope this helps others!